# Fast forward merge after git flow hotfix

Tags: git, merge, git-flow, fast-forward, git-history

I have three branches production , develop and a fix branch as shown below (A,B and C are commits) :

```
  A (production,fix)
   \   
    B   (develop)
```

I want to be able to only perform fast forward merges using the git flow strategy . However on the scenario where fix and develop have been moved to newer commit C this cant be done f.e.:

```
    C (fix)                           C (fix,production)
   /                                /
  A (production)     --->>         A 
   \                                \
    B (develop)                      B (develop)
```

I would avoid rebasing develop as it is a public branch . Is there a different way I can achieve only fast forward merges (thus keeping a clean history) without having to rebase the development branch ?

Comment: How would the resulting graph look? If you can't come up with such a result graph that you like, the answer seems to be "no". There is no inheritant problem with rebasing even published feature branches, it just may be people that are not prepared for it and need to read up on how to deal with an upstream rebase.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Note the ask wouldn't be rebasing a "feature branch" but instead a shared trunk branch that all feature branches are based on (called `develop` in Git Flow). Your point is valid that devs could be taught how to deal with even a rebased shared branch, however, that would require a lot of synchronization and potentially advanced Git users, enough that it it's not really a consideration for a normal workflow. (Though it may still be done in rare circumstances.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a different way I can achieve only fast forward merges (thus keeping a clean history) without having to rebase the development branch ?

No. When you merge two branches, if the two branches have diverged, you must either have a merge commit, or you must rewrite at least one of the branches such that it is based off of the other. There is no way around this.

**Side Note:** One of the great features of Git is the fact that simultaneous development can be easily merged, which has the side effect of producing merge commits (if you don't wish to rewrite either development path). Note also, since you mentioned Git Flow, that merge commits are highly recommended in your scenario, for multiple reasons.

Comment: And what these reasons might be ?

Comment: @CapBarracudas The 2 main reasons [Git Flow recommends using `--no-ff`](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#incorporating-a-finished-feature-on-develop) to create merge commits is so you can see which group of commits constituted a feature, and when necessary, it's easier to revert an entire feature by reverting a single merge commit, instead of having to revert every individual commit. Also, on `master` (or `production` in your case), you can do `git log --first-parent production` to see every release to Prod and compare them. (Note, you could do that with tags as well.)

Comment: @CapBarracudas For feature branches I strongly prefer rebasing before forcing a merge commit to get a nice looking graph, and there is another minor advantage of still forcing the merge commit: If you follow the standard of 50 chars or less for commit message titles, you can now put the feature title in the merge commit, and the action commit titles in each individual commit brought in by that merge commit. That being said, if you squash merge your feature branches, the `--no-ff` is probably pointless there. (But still useful for merging `develop` into `production` and vice versa.)